# CSS background images failed after converting HTML to PHP

Tags: php, css

I'm building a website use PHP. I finished all `html`, `css`, `js` at first just as the picture shows.

And then I begin to convert `html` to `php`.

However, after converting `html` to `php`, the background image in `css` fails.
I have checked the path, it works in the html.

[image: my files]

I have no idea what's wrong with the code.

Need I do any special operate to CSS when I convert html to PHP?

```
body {
    background: url('../img/bg3.jpg') center;
    position: relative;
    height:1300px;
}

#wrapper{  height:1500px;}

#wrapper{overflow: hidden;}
.wrapper-head {
    background: black url('../img/head.jpg') center no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 908px;
    height: 178px;
    margin-top: 39px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    box-shadow: -2px 0 20px 1px #7f7e7f, 0 -2px 20px 1px #7f7e7f, 2px 0 20px 1px #7f7e7f;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ff0000;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper-head img {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper-nav {
    background: url('../img/nav.jpg') center no-repeat;
    width: 1009px;
    height: 83px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, -33px);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -33px);
    /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0px, -33px);
    /* Standard syntax */
    margin-bottom: 0px;[![enter image description here][2]][2]
    color: #281d04;
}
```

The whole path is:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myblog/petshop/public
```

something special is that, when I open this path:

```
http://localhost/petshop/public/img/bg3.jpg
```

it says:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

Other photo used in html from the same folder can work,only the three in css fails.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: What do you mean converting HTML to PHP? The HTML can be put in the PHP file outside the <?php ?> tags.

Comment: Could it be your PHP file is in a different location as you HTML file?

Comment: Search and replace on all your files "index.html to index.php". There are nothing elso to do when you change a HTML file in PHP.
I guess there are a wrong path in your css. Could you provide your entire code ?

Comment: Yes,I just post the css code and the path.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve the issue!It cost me a night!It is my first time to change html into php,so very excited!Thanks Lord!I prayed,and solved!

Actually,it is very easy,just because the photos is protected,I made them readable.That's it!